# How to store triangular (upper/lower) matrix into a single file using mpi with parallel hdf5?

Tags: c, matrix, mpi, hdf5, triangular

I have a 1 million x 1 million double floating point matrix (table) that want to store in a single hdf5 file, the matrix itself is symmetric therefore only lower/upper triangle is needed, the code that write this matrix is an mpi code, so each mpi process will write part of the matrix (a block or a triangle), the triangular matrix will look like the below, each p[i] represent a matrix value calculated by process i:

```
p0 
p0 p0
p0 p0 p0
p0 p0 p0 p0
p1 p1 p1 p1 p2
p1 p1 p1 p1 p2 p2
p1 p1 p1 p1 p2 p2 p2
p1 p1 p1 p1 p2 p2 p2 p2
p3 p3 p3 p3 p4 p4 p4 p4 p5
p3 p3 p3 p3 p4 p4 p4 p4 p5 p5
p3 p3 p3 p3 p4 p4 p4 p4 p5 p5 p5
p3 p3 p3 p3 p4 p4 p4 p4 p5 p5 p5 p5
```

From my current understanding the final hdf5 memory space can be a flattened version of the above triangle to a 1D vector that store the entire half matrix, so the actual final data in hdf5 can be:

```
p0 p0 p0 p0 p0 p0 p0 p0 p0 p0 p1 p1 p1 p1 p2 p1 p1 p1 p1 p2 p2 p1 p1 p1 p1 p2 p2 p2 p1 p1 p1 p1 p2 p2 p2 p2 p3 p3 p3 p3 p4 p4 p4 p4 p5 p3 p3 p3 p3 p4 p4 p4 p4 p5 p5 p3 p3 p3 p3 p4 p4 p4 p4 p5 p5 p5 p3 p3 p3 p3 p4 p4 p4 p4 p5 p5 p5 p5
```

I am really very new to hdf5 so could you please tell the correct way to for each process to send its data to the correct position in the final hdf5 file? It seems I will need to use hyperslab however I will need to break the hyperslab from each process into multiple pieces with start, stride, offset, so that data from each process can find its location in the final 1D vector, but is that type of operation actually supported by hdf5?

Hopefully I have made my problem clear, and thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HDF5 there is no real difference for parallel and serial writing (just a few flags).
1) Are you sure your cluster support HDF5 parallel? (if not just do it in serial: in a loop over each process)

If yes:

first you need to open the file:

```
plist_id = H5Pcreate(H5P_FILE_ACCESS);
H5Pset_fapl_mpio(plist_id, comm, info);
file_id = H5Fcreate(filename_str.c_str(), H5F_ACC_EXCL, H5P_DEFAULT,plist_id);
```

then during the writing you set the "parallel write"

```
plist_id = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_XFER);
H5Pset_dxpl_mpio(plist_id, H5FD_MPIO_COLLECTIVE);
status = H5Dwrite(dset_id, dtype_id, memspace, filespace, plist_id, data);
```

All other manipulation are the same in parallel or serial.

To select an hyperslabe use the method: H5Sselect_hyperslab, this method allow you to select an hyperslab in both the memspace and the filespace, it allow you to specify the offset, stride, count.

The doc is a nightmare for HDF5 parallel, but can be very usefull :-).
This file is a good example how to use hdf5-parallel.

https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/parallel/coll_test.c

Comment: Thanks, David, at last I turned to the solution that each mpi rank write its own block and use another piece of code to rebuild the matrix, the previous way was rather complicated and will actually slow down a lot for performance, as you mentioned, the doc is really terrible...:-P